# How can I include '\n' into the while (cin >> x) idiom?

Tags: c++

My understanding is that the operator `>>` returns the left operand, so `cin >> x` returns `cin` which has a value of `false` if we encounter an `EOF` or other errors. Now my guess is that since `cin` skips whitespace, characters like `\n` don't get stored. What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
int x;

while((cin >> x) and x != '\n')
    // do stuff
```

So that when `cin` encounters a newline in the stream, it exits the input loop (as it would normally do with say, `EOF`).

Comment: It doesn't necessarily return the left operand. In this case, it does.

Comment: are you trying to change the idiom to only respond to `'\n'` or add `'\n'` to the general cin response to things like `EOF`?

Comment: Perhaps you should check what `x` really is if you only press enter.

Comment: @Yoel - I would like the loop to terminate when the input stream comes across a new line - probably not by modifying `cin` in any way, but whatever would be simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `>>` operator directly won't work, because as you say it skips whitespace including newlines.

What you can do is to read a single line using `std::getline`, and then you can read all input from the line with `std::stringstream`.

```
std::string line;
if (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    std::istringstream ss(line);
    int x;
    while (ss >> x) {
        //....
    }
}
```